# Approval Workflow - unexpected error after parallel approval

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, content-approval, error-handling

I currently have a SharePoint 2010 calendar approval workflow that I'm using which uses the OOB Approval process workflow with parallel approvers.  I currently have it so if one of the approvers, approves the item then it sets the content approval to Approved and end the workflow.
[image]
[image: completion]

The approval process works, however, if an approver already approves the request and then another approver goes in to approve the same request, they get "An unexpected error has occurred." I currently have the approval

[image]

I currently have the approval link in the emails going directly to the [%Current Task:Form_URN%] which is when the error comes up.

Any suggestions on what I can do to either have them go to a new form stating that it has already been completed or at the very least stop it from coming up with the "unexpected error"?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Have you pulled the logs and checked the correlation id given? What does the error state? I would think at that point, that task has ended and so the Form_URN link is no longer relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the server logs but I'm assuming that the issue is with the FormURN as well. Looking for suggestions on what else I could try, maybe supply a message in place of the form or something.

Comment: Have you checked your workflow history list? It should give some sort of error or reason it failed.

Comment: If it is indeed the workflow that is causing the issue, you could add another column to your calendar list, and then set it to "already approved" or something like that. Then in your workflow, check that column first. If its not set to that, then run the workflow.

Comment: It's only when issuing the FormURN from the email.  Does it initiate the workflow when going to the task form or did the task form initiate the workflow?